# How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer 9 thru http response headers in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to restrict caching of a PDF file, by setting the below headers in java code:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
```

This is working fine with IE 8. However it is failing with IE 9 and it is still caching the file in the temoporary internet files folder.

Can anyone please throw some light on it?

Thanks & Regards,

Rama

Answer (score 1):

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1L);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
```

Is what I typically use.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this and it works.

```
// Set to expire far in the past.
response.setHeader("Expires", "Mon, 23 Aug 1982 12:00:00 GMT");

// Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

// Set IE extended HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers (use addHeader).
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");

// Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just with this it works for me on Ie9

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");<br/>
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");<br/><br/>
```

But if i add

```
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");<br/>
```

then it does **NOT** work...

Please refer to:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/20/using-post_2d00_check-and-pre_2d00_check-cache-directives.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
```

Is what you presumably want.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that header and it is not working.From the HTTP header documentation, I could see that no-store is better option than no-cache and it is working fine with IE 8 but not with IE 9.

Comment: I've not got the code at hand, but I've used this before. I believe the headers were as edited above.

Comment: Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE9 but you may want to explore further on [***Cache-Control***](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)